# calling opencv c++ code in C# application

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I have developed a c++ program which uses OpenCV. Now i want to develop a windows form based application in C#.
As C# can only handle managed code it is nearly impossible to run OpenCV directly on C# application. I have searched for different ways to create C# application using OpenCV, one of which is EmguCV and the other method that i am much more interested in is importing the c++ .dll file in C# application and calling the unmanaged functions this way.

I started by creating simple functions in c++ and i was able to use `cout` and `cin` in my C# application by importing the dll. The problem comes when i try to include OpenCV header files in my c++ application and when i compile i get this error

> error LNK1104: cannot open file 'tbb_debug.lib'

Some one has done this before but i cant figure out how he interface c++ with C# in 
[Displaying webcam feed in cv::Mat format in a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616529/displaying-webcam-feed-in-cvmat-format-in-a-picturebox)

The Question is that i have function which takes in a cv::Mat variable and performs some image processing on it and returns the processed matrix. i want to use that function written in c++ in my C# application. but the problem is that i am unable to create the dll when i include OpenCV library in c++.

> So please Don't Suggest me to use EmguCV or any other .NET wrappers
>   for OpenCV.

i am using Visual Studio 2010 for my Project.

Comment: What is the question? You've already mentioned, that you can create a DLL and access it by P/Invoke. You may also use C++/CLI to write an assembly, which accesses native headers and use native libraries. As for the link error, you provided not enough information for us to tell, what is wrong.

Comment: i have edited the post, when i try to write any method that uses OpenCV i get an error that i have posted above so the dll cannot be created but when i used only cout and cin no error came up and the dll was created sucessfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would explicitly export methods that wrap your entry points in a C++ header, and then use P/Invoke to reference them:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL DoSomething();
```

Then consume them in the C#:

```
[DllImport("MyOpenCVWrapper.dll")]
private static extern bool DoSomething();
```

I wouldn't try to reference the OpenCV headers.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might not be what you're looking for, I did that task with C++/CLI and exposed it through an assembly.  It was straight forward and worked pretty well.  [Blog article here](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2009/03/24/face-detection-with-dotimage-and-opencv.aspx).