# Integrate Opencv dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll, computer-vision

I have created a project which uses opencv dll to read and display images. Now, I want to convert this read-display project to a dll which will inturn be used in a C# project. Any suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be specific about the coding problem you're having.

Comment: I have tried that years ago you can find the solution in question posted by me [Calling open CV in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493149/calling-opencv-c-code-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan. I have a project(say Project A) which uses opencv to read and display images. And I have another project(say B) in c#. Now, I need to create a dll of Project A and import it in Project B. So, when i create my own dll(Project A dll) it gives me an import error("dll not found") in Project B, however I have checked all the paths and they seem correct.

Comment: @VallabhKaranjkar please follow [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tanmayit08/unmanaged-cpp-dll-call-from-managed-C-Sharp-application/)
 tutorial to create c++ dll.

Comment: If you don't have much dependencies from C++, I would recommend you to use emguCV.

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan Thank you for your help!