# OpenCV Webcam feed not displaying in PictureBox visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, opencv, video-capture

Hi so I used opencv to get webcam feed from my default camera and I wish to display it in a picturebox on my windows form. My webcam comes on but for some reason, the feed is never displayed on my picturebox. Please could someone help point out/solve the issue as I am stuck here right now.
Thanks in advance.

In myform.h, I have this code to send the picturebox to the myform.cpp file:

```
System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ mypicbox1(void)  
{
    opencv_gui::MyForm aform;
    return aform.pictureBox1;
}
```

and the code to draw get the videofeed and put into my picture box in myform.cpp is:

```
void opencv_gui::DrawCvImage(const cv::Mat& cvImage)
{
    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pictureBox = mypicbox1();
    // only color images are supported
    assert(cvImage.type() == CV_8UC3);

    if ((pictureBox->Image == nullptr) || (pictureBox->Width != cvImage.cols) || (pictureBox->Height != cvImage.rows))
    {
        pictureBox->Width = cvImage.cols;
        pictureBox->Height = cvImage.rows;
        pictureBox->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows);
    }

    // Create System::Drawing::Bitmap from cv::Mat
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmpImage = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(
        cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows, cvImage.step,
        System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,
        System::IntPtr(cvImage.data)
    );

    // Draw Bitmap over a PictureBox
    System::Drawing::Graphics^ g = System::Drawing::Graphics::FromImage(pictureBox->Image);

    g->DrawImage(bmpImage, 0, 0, cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows);
    pictureBox->Refresh();

    delete g;
}


//camera feed
int opencv_gui::video_cap(void)
{
    VideoCapture cap;

    if (!cap.open(0)) // open the default camera (camera 0), use something different from 0 otherwise;
        return 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) break; // end of video stream
        DrawCvImage(frame);
        if (waitKey(10) == 27) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC 
    }
    // the camera will be closed automatically upon exit
    // cap.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my debug log: I have used arrows like ">>>>>>>" to show important parameters and the words "RED >>>>>>>" to show error parameters.

- cvImage { flags=1124024336 dims=2 rows=480 ...} cv::Mat&
- allocator   0x0000000000000000  cv::MatAllocator*

  > > > > > > > cols    640 int
- > > > > > > > data    0x0000026AC2146F80  unsigned char*
  > > > > > > >               *(*cvImage).data    0 ''    unsigned char
- dataend 0x0000026AC2227F80  unsigned char*
- datalimit   0x0000026AC2227F80  unsigned char*
- datastart   0x0000026AC2146F80  unsigned char*
      dims    2   int
      flags   1124024336  int
      rows    480 int
- > > > > > > > size    { p=0x000000DBDFF0DE80 }    cv::MatSize
- > > > > > > > p   0x000000DBDFF0DE80  int*
  > > > > > > >               *(*cvImage).size.p  0   int
- step    { p=0x000000DBDFF0DEC8 buf={Length=2} } cv::MatStep
- buf {Length=2}  unsigned __int64[]
- p   0x000000DBDFF0DEC8  unsigned __int64*
- u   0x0000026AA4814780  cv::UMatData*
- RED >>>>>>> bmpImage    0x0000026aa62a1fd0 { defaultTransparentColor= }    System::Drawing::Bitmap^
- RED >>>>>>> System::Drawing::Image^ 0x0000026aa62a1fd0 { nativeImage=2657511292512 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
      defaultTransparentColor    System::Drawing::Color
      g      System::Drawing::Graphics^
- RED >>>>>>> pictureBox  0x0000026aa62a1388 { borderStyle=System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::None image=0x0000026aa62a1fa0 sizeMode=System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Normal ...}    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^
- RED >>>>>>> System::Windows::Forms::Control^    0x0000026aa62a1388 { ControlKeyboardRouting= PaletteTracing= FocusTracing= ...}  System::Windows::Forms::Control^
      AllowDrop   false   bool
      BorderStyle System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::None   System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle
      CausesValidation    true    bool
- CreateParams    0x0000026aa62a15d8 { className= caption= style=1442840576 ...}    System::Windows::Forms::CreateParams^
      DefaultImeMode  System::Windows::Forms::ImeMode::Disable    System::Windows::Forms::ImeMode
- DefaultSize {Width=100 Height=50}   System::Drawing::Size
      EVENT_SIZEMODECHANGED   0x0000026aa629af50  System::Object^
- ErrorImage  0x0000026aa629b110 { nativeImage=2657511192608 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
- Font    0x0000026aa6280148 {}   System::Drawing::Font^
- ForeColor   {RGB=0x0}   System::Drawing::Color
- Image   0x0000026aa62a1fa0 { nativeImage=2657511290992 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
- [System::Drawing::Bitmap^]  0x0000026aa62a1fa0 { defaultTransparentColor= }    System::Drawing::Bitmap^
- System::MarshalByRefObject^ 0x0000026aa62a1fa0 { __identity= } System::MarshalByRefObject^
      Flags   2   int
- FrameDimensionsList {Length=1}  array ^
      Height  480 int
      HorizontalResolution    96.000000   float
- Palette 0x0000026aa62a25e8 { flags=1129621568 entries={Length=0} }  System::Drawing::Imaging::ColorPalette^
- PhysicalDimension   { width=640.00000 height=480.00000 }    System::Drawing::SizeF
      PixelFormat System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format32bppArgb  System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat
      PropertyIdList  {Length=0}  array ^
      PropertyItems   {Length=0}  array ^
- RawFormat   0x0000026aa62a3488 { ...}   System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat^
- Size    {Width=640 Height=480}  System::Drawing::Size
      Tag    System::Object^
      VerticalResolution  96.000000   float
      Width   640 int
      nativeImage 2657511290992   __int64
      rawData    array ^
      userData       System::Object^
      ImageLocation      System::String^
- ImageRectangle  {X=0 Y=0 Width=640 Height=480}  System::Drawing::Rectangle
      ImeMode System::Windows::Forms::ImeMode::Disable    System::Windows::Forms::ImeMode
- InitialImage    0x0000026aa629c568 { nativeImage=2657511196256 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
      PICTUREBOXSTATE_asyncOperationInProgress    1   int
      PICTUREBOXSTATE_cancellationPending 2   int
      PICTUREBOXSTATE_inInitialization    64  int
      PICTUREBOXSTATE_needToLoadImageLocation 32  int
      PICTUREBOXSTATE_useDefaultErrorImage    8   int
      PICTUREBOXSTATE_useDefaultInitialImage  4   int
      PICTUREBOXSTATE_waitOnLoad  16  int
      RightToLeft System::Windows::Forms::RightToLeft::No System::Windows::Forms::RightToLeft
      SizeMode    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Normal  System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode
      TabIndex    1   int
      TabStop false   bool
      Text    ""  System::String^
      WaitOnLoad  false   bool
      borderStyle System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle::None   System::Windows::Forms::BorderStyle
      contentLength   0   int
      currentAsyncLoadOperation      System::ComponentModel::AsyncOperation^
      currentlyAnimating  false   bool
- defaultErrorImage   0x0000026aa629b110 { nativeImage=2657511192608 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
- defaultErrorImageForThread  0x0000026aa629b110 { nativeImage=2657511192608 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
      defaultErrorImageKey    0x0000026aa629af08  System::Object^
- defaultInitialImage 0x0000026aa629c568 { nativeImage=2657511196256 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
- defaultInitialImageForThread    0x0000026aa629c568 { nativeImage=2657511196256 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
      defaultInitialImageKey  0x0000026aa629aef0  System::Object^
- errorImage  0x0000026aa629b110 { nativeImage=2657511192608 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
      handleValid false   bool
- image   0x0000026aa62a1fa0 { nativeImage=2657511290992 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
      imageInstallationType   ImageInstallationType::DirectlySpecified    ImageInstallationType
      imageLocation      System::String^
- initialImage    0x0000026aa629c568 { nativeImage=2657511196256 rawData= userData= }   System::Drawing::Image^
- [System::Drawing::Bitmap^]  0x0000026aa629c568 { defaultTransparentColor= }    System::Drawing::Bitmap^
- System::MarshalByRefObject^ 0x0000026aa629c568 { __identity= } System::MarshalByRefObject^
      Flags   73744   int
- FrameDimensionsList {Length=1}  array ^
      Height  16  int
      HorizontalResolution    96.000000   float
- RED >>>>>>>Palette 0x0000026aa629ea60 { flags=951278840 entries={Length=0} }   System::Drawing::Imaging::ColorPalette^
- PhysicalDimension   { width=14.000000 height=16.000000 }    System::Drawing::SizeF
      PixelFormat System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb   System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat
      PropertyIdList  {Length=0}  array ^
      PropertyItems   {Length=0}  array ^
- RED >>>>>>> RawFormat   0x0000026aa629f900 { ...}   System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat^
- Size    {Width=14 Height=16}    System::Drawing::Size
      Tag    System::Object^
      VerticalResolution  96.000000   float
      Width   14  int
      nativeImage 2657511196256   __int64
      rawData    array ^
      userData       System::Object^
  RED >>>>>>> internalSyncObject  0x0000026aa629d900  System::Object^
      loadCompletedDelegate      System::Threading::SendOrPostCallback^
      loadCompletedKey    0x0000026aa629af20  System::Object^
      loadProgressChangedKey  0x0000026aa629af38  System::Object^
      loadProgressDelegate       System::Threading::SendOrPostCallback^
      localImageStreamReader     System::IO::StreamReader^
- pictureBoxState { data=12 } System::Collections::Specialized::BitVector32
      readBlockSize   4096    int
      readBuffer     array ^
- savedSize   {Width=640 Height=480}  System::Drawing::Size
      sizeMode    System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Normal  System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode
      tempDownloadStream     System::IO::MemoryStream^
      totalBytesRead  0   int
      uriImageStream     System::IO::Stream^

Comment: Since I don't see any synchronization, I assume `opencv_gui::video_cap` runs on the main GUI thread. As such, seeing an infinite loop there is already a sign of potential trouble. While `waitKey` might kinda-sorta work in, I wouldn't rely on that for anything other than the OpenCV UI. This is a pretty awkward design in a GUI app anyway. You already wait between frames, so why not use a timer?

Comment: Thanks Dan for the comment, I intend to clean up the code soon regarding the loop but removing the loop and capturing manually still doesn't display frames on the picture box which is my main issue.

Comment: Can you try to step through that function in the debugger? What are the values of `cvImage.cols, cvImage.rows, cvImage.step` ? Does `cvImage.data` contain some reasonable values? BTW, OpenCV images are BGR, and you interpret the data as RGB. You probably need a `cvtColor` there to switch it around.

Comment: Hi Dan, I have put a copy of my debug log into the question. The image size and data parameters are zero but the other parameters have reasonable value(640 and 480)...I have also signified which of the debug lines were highlighted in red for you to look at. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to edit my code a bit but I pretty much solved my issue using the answer provided here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12628861/5728859

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private: System::Void button2_MouseClick(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e)
{
    if (button2->Text == "Stop")
    {
        button2->Text = "Start";

    }
    else if (button2->Text == "Start")
    {
        button2->Text = "Stop";

    }

     VideoCapture capture(0);
     Mat frame;

     while (button2->Text == "Stop")
     {
         capture.read(frame);
         System::Drawing::Graphics^ graphics2 = pictureBox1->CreateGraphics();
         System::IntPtr ptr2(frame.ptr());
         System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b2 = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame.cols,
             frame.rows, frame.step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr2);
         System::Drawing::RectangleF rect2(0, 0, pictureBox1->Width, pictureBox1->Height);
         graphics2->DrawImage(b2, rect2);

     }
 }
```